# How to disable field validation on MVC view?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have an MVC 3 application. 
I have a model called UserModel that contains an email field, validated for unique with RemoteAttribute. I want to use UserModel on 2 Views - EditUser and CreateUser. How can I permit validation of email field on  EditUser view(because there this field is readonly), and leave it on CreateUser view?

Comment: Do you mean:- only validate the email on the CreateUser view, as it is readonly on EditUser view?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I mean. For Now, I decided to have 2 different models, inherited from base for this reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the partial validation technique to modify the validation results. This example will discard any errors for the Email field.

```
public class DontValidateEmailAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {

  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
    var modelState = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState; 
    var incomingValues = filterContext.Controller.ValueProvider;

    var key = modelState.Keys.Single(x => incomingValues.Equals("Email"));    
    modelState[key].Errors.Clear();

  }
}
```

and apply this attribute to your Edit Controller.

I learnt this technique from [Steve Sanderson's Pro ASP NET MVC 3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430234040). He uses the technique to validate a model that has required fields but the data entry is a multistep wizard. If the value has not been returned in the form post, he removes the errors for that property.

Comment: hm.... maybe this sounds a bit weird, but I'm using the same controller for create and edit operations.  Maybe this is the reason to make some refactoring

Comment: A quick fix would be to create a hidden field for Email on the Edit view so then it would get returned in the post and would exist and be valid.

Comment: Heh))) Nice hack, probably it will work. I will use this, after some time of searching for better solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A good way to solve this is to pass the usermodel id as an adittional field into the remote validation method.  This will be blank or null on create but populated on edit.  You can then add logic to the remote validation method to check the id.
See example below

```
[Remote("ValidationMethod", "UserModel", AdditionalFields = "Id", ErrorMessage = "Error message")]
```