# MVC 4: How to use the "partial validation" technique?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, validation, compiler-errors

I'd need to implement the "partial validation technique" on MVC 4, as reported in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8183583/1129461) too:

```
      public class DontValidateEmailAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute 
         {  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) 
                 {
                    var modelState = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState;     
                    var incomingValues = filterContext.Controller.ValueProvider;    
                    var key = modelState.Keys.Single(x => incomingValues.Equals("Email"));
                    modelState[key].Errors.Clear();  
                  }
          }
```

But I get the following **compile error**: "`'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Single' and no extension method 'Single' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`..."

THX

Comment: Are you missing `using System.Linq` up top?

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. IF you put as answer I willingly mark as a valid reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `using System.Linq` on the top?